# Foreign data and garbage collection

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, ffi

When I allocate some data via FFI and associate a finalizer with it, I get a `ForeignPtr` in Haskell. When this pointer becomes unreferenced, GC collects the pointer, which causes finalizer to run. But the collecting only happens when GC has run and "unreferencing" doesn't force GC to run. I.e. there can be many pointers lying around, but since pointers themselves do not occupy much memory, RTS simply doesn't see a reason to start GC, because the size of foreign data is not tracked by the RTS, according to my [investigations](https://github.com/effectfully/haskell-ffi-example/blob/f7837c4304442a3b595caf0533dae1d47a78ab66/src/Main.hs#L28). Is this correct?

How do I communicate "when this pointer becomes unreferenced, collect it immediately" to the RTS? Are there any flags that allow to control when to start GC? Is this a problem for a real program (as any real program always has enough explicit garbage to stimulate GC)?

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.tweag.io/posts/2017-11-29-linear-jvm.html) talks about this problem. It is a good summary of the current state of the art for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RTS has no idea whether any piece of data is unreferenced until GC is run. GHC does not have reference counting GC, which would allow immediate action on garbage. You could try to implement reference counting yourself, or use manual GC from [`System.Mem`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-Mem.html).

Foreign allocation isn't tracked in Haskell-land. If you want more control, but no custom GC or reference counting, you can use e. g. [`Foreign.Marhsal.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html) for manual/scoped allocation and deallocation.

Another option is to use pinned allocation in GHC RTS. This gives you memory which is not moved by GC. References to pinned data can be passed to foreign code without overhead, but pinned data is tracked, can be GC-d, and triggers GC the same way as usual heap data does. [Here's](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6/candidate/docs/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html) one API for pinned data. Another choice is simply [`ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html). The possible drawback of pinned data is memory fragmentation and slower allocation, but that also holds for (any) foreign allocation which returns stable pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding when a pointer becomes unreferenced is not trivial. 
As far as I know, there is no way to perform what you request, namely inform the GC that a pointer is now no longer reachable. At best, one can trigger a GC cycle, but there are no hard guarantees.

From your description, you probably would prefer a reference-counting mechanism instead of garbage collection. However, especially in complex pure code, it is hard to identify the points where the counter should be incremented or decremented: it would be easier in a state or IO-based monad where such side effects are properly sequenced w.r.t. the rest of the computation.

If you don't really need reference counting beyond "one", a somehow common idiom is using a `with`-style function for handling the allocation and deallocation. 
This can get a bit tricky to handle correctly.

For instance, a trivial implementation could be

```
-- very simplified code
withMyResource :: (ResourcePtr -> IO r) -> IO r
withMyResource action = do
   p <- allocResourcePtr
   result <- action p
   deallocResourcePtr p
   return result
```

This can then be used as

```
withResource $ \ptr -> do
   use ptr
```

Note that this is not completely safe, since one might return the pointer, making it live after its deallocation

```
ptr <- withResource return
use ptr -- dangerous!
```

A properly pointer-handling routine should work like the `ST` monad and its tagged `STRef`s, which are designed so to prevent pointers to escape their intended scope (as done above). This exploits rank-2 types, but is effective.

Still, one can live with the naive `with` routine, and just be careful to not let pointers escape.

Another unsafety issue is caused by `action` being able to throw exceptions. (This can be handled using `bracket`-like routines from the library).